# Como Desabilitar Botão de Voltar React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Olá, gostaria de saber como eu debilito o botão de voltar da createMaterialTopTabNavigator, do react-native, na versão 5.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Consegui Desabilitar o botão nativo dessa forma:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {createMaterialTopTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
import Agenda from '../pages/agenda';
import Pacientes from '../pages/pacientes';
import Exames from '../pages/exames';
import {BackHandler} from 'react-native';

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

export default function SismedRoutes() {
  useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => true);
    return () =>
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => true);
  }, []);
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Agenda">
      <Tab.Screen name="Agenda" component={Agenda} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Pacientes" component={Pacientes} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Exames" component={Exames} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

///Substitua o estado da navegaçao atual por uma nova
//valor do index será a rota ativa atual
Lembrando que se voce tem tres telas e ta na primeira, nela não vai aparecer o botao de voltar pq nao tem pra onde voltar, agora digamos que voce esteja na tela de login queira depois de logar nao deixar deixa a pessoa voltar atraves do botao pra tela anterior, ai esse codigo a baixo seria a opção certo. Observando ainda que teria que desabilitar o botao fisico tambem

navigation.reset({
index: 0,
routes: [{ name: 'Profile' }],
});
Referencia de : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#reset

Comment: Obrigado amigo, era exatamente isso que eu estava procurando. Abraços!

Answer (score -2):

para funcionar apenas no componente ou página desejada, colocar dentro da função ou const do componente:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const backAction = () => {
      return true;
    };

    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', backAction);

    return () => backHandler.remove();
  }, []);
```